# PLSQL Convert String to Datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-date-functions

The 'closed_date' column and 'submit_date' are loaded into Oracle as strings, they look like this:

8/17/2017 12:41 (in 24hrs)

How can I convert this string format into date in the format of 
mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss

Thank you!

Comment: Something is very wrong with your question. If the input string is too short (for example it is missing seconds where the date format expects it) you would get a very different error: **ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format**. The error you shared, **ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string**, means just the opposite: your input string is too **long** and the format doesn't have enough elements to convert it. So **something** in what you told us is **not true.** Please research it and then edit your post to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your date format, you don't want seconds:

```
select to_date(CLOSED_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') as CLOSED_DATE,
       to_date(SUBMIT_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') as SUBMIT_DATE
from s_daily_ops
```

Answer (score 0):

Tack on a trailing ':00', or remove ':ss' from your format string.